# Counts and proportions within nested dataframes

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to count and calculate proportions within several subdataframes. I used to do this with some ugly code, using lapply and creating and looping over many objects. With the purrr package this should be more straightforward, however I didn't manage to do it so far.

Illustration with the standard R dataset "mtcars":

The following code is a standard dplyr solution (which works):
 `mtcars%>% group_by(vs, am) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(freq = prop.table(n))`

Thus, I get the proportions  and counts within the levels of "vs" (0 and 1). However, I want to calculate the grouped counts and proportions within several subgroups of "carb". So with standard dplyr this would look like that (works as well):

`mtcars %>% filter(carb == 1) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(freq = prop.table(n))`
`mtcars %>% filter(carb == 2) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(freq = prop.table(n))`
etc.

This works but is cumbersome.

With Purrr it should look something like that:
`mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% nest() %>% mutate(n = map(data, count))`

Here however, the grouping `group_by(vs, am)`  is lost. How can I introduce the grouping here?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired ouput?

```r
library(tidyverse)

unique(mtcars$carb) %>% map_dfr(~ mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs, am) %>%
  filter(carb == .x) %>%
  summarise(carb = .x, n = n(),.groups = 'drop') %>%
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  mutate(freq = prop.table(n)))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#> # Groups:   vs [2]
#>       vs    am  carb     n  freq
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     0     0     4     5 0.625
#>  2     0     1     4     3 0.375
#>  3     1     0     4     2 1    
#>  4     1     0     1     3 0.429
#>  5     1     1     1     4 0.571
#>  6     0     0     2     4 0.8  
#>  7     0     1     2     1 0.2  
#>  8     1     0     2     2 0.4  
#>  9     1     1     2     3 0.6  
#> 10     0     0     3     3 1    
#> 11     0     1     6     1 1    
#> 12     0     1     8     1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>